# Who is a major opponent in Dungeon Siege III?

Tags: achievements, dungeon-siege-3

In Dungeon Siege III, the trophy/achievement *I Could Do This Blindfolded* reads:

> You defeated a major opponent using only your default equipment.

What opponents are deemed "major"? Bosses? If so, are all bosses considered major opponents, even the ones at the start of the game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on posts that I've read online, it only counts major bosses, ones that are a significant part of the storyline.  Rajani is the first one that I've seen confirmation of qualifying.  So you need to get to that battle, then equip your characters starting equipment, probably switch the difficulty to casual, and then win .  Note that your allies can have whatever equipment they want, it is only the main character that needs to be wearing the default.

Answer (score 2):

- Rajani (Ravens Rill)
- Uramesh (Swamps)
- Dapper Old Gent (Stonebridge [Causeway])
- Jayne Kassynda
- Corrupted Creator God (Mournweld)

I have played several thousand play-throughs and these are the only characters I can find to trigger this trophy.  If you find another please add to this post.

*Just a side note.... I find the easiest to complete is with Anjali (constantly heal and use immolation with healing build and Lucas as companion.  There are other combos that work, but this is easiest.  And make sure you do it on easy unless you are a masochist

Comment: Several thousand play-throughs of DS3?  Wow, I couldn't even stomach one.